# Looping over a table and parsing data of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table,

```
incassoid  Amount      Details
=========  ======   ===============
   1       1.0000   5||0.4999;7||0.0001;9||0.0500
   2       2.0000   3||1.0000;15||1.0000
   3       1.0000   8||1.0000
```

where in detail column, `5||0.4999` means `5` is a `productid` and `0.4999` is the money product has,what I need is to get the values from the details section and represent it in the table, It needs to loop over all the `incassoid`, and for each `incassoid`, I need the details like this, As an example for `incassoid` `1`, it should show its detail like this,

```
incassoid  Productid   productamount   amount  
=========  =========   ============   =========
   1           5          0.4999         1
   1           7          0.0001         1
   1           9          0.0500         1
```

I am trying to find a way to parse the details section, but I am not sure how should I do this, Can some one please help me out in this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I guess you already have noticed, but never store data like that. Have separate columns for the different details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL split values to multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: Even if you do that somehow, this is never going to be efficient enough to put it into production. You should have separate table for details that should look exactly like the result that you expect.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you...I also think that data should not be stored like this, but the place where I do my internship, have it like this. I think they should change it but they have it for so many years that they don't want to do that   :( So I was trying to parse it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have a table of products

Table products

```
  id
------
    3
    5
    7
    8
    9
   15
```

You can use that request to do what you want

```
select t.incassoid, p.id productid,
       substring_index(substring_index(t.details, concat(p.id, '||'), -1), ';', 1) productamount,
       t.amount
from products p, tablename t
where find_in_set(p.id, (select group_concat(p2.id)
                         from products p2, tablename t2
                         where t2.incassoid = t.incassoid
                           and (t2.details like concat(p2.id, '||%')
                                or t2.details like concat('%;', p2.id, '||%'))))
```

The subrequest in the find_in_set extract a list of product ids from details.
Then, for each details (of tablename), the find_in_set filter is used to join the correct list of products.

After that we just have to extract the amount of product in details.

SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dfd4/1/0